# C# Dns.GetHostEntry and binding to specified IP

Tags: c#, binding, ip

I want to use Dns.GetHostEntry (C# .NET) to resolve domains. Because of a lot of domains to resolve, alot of connections to be made to DNS Server, I'm worry DNS Server will refuse the connection. I also want to speed up these tasks too.

And my server has many IPs, I need a way to split the task to multithread, and every thread will use 1 IP to resolve the domains.

Do you know any way to bind to specified IP address before using Dns.GetHostEntry to resolve?

Comment: have you tried a goolge search on the following..? 
`C# stackoverflow bind to specified IP address before using Dns.GetHostEntry`

Comment: sure, I searched but no suitable result found